# Is it possible to do nth child of nth child in css pseudo classes?

Tags: css, class, css-selectors

I basically want to do "the 2nd column then the second one down" within that column. So go two across in a menu then two down.

Thanks.

```
 <div class="row ms-category">    
            <div class="col-category col-xs-3">
                <a class="form-group level1" href="">title</a>
                <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>   
                <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>
           </div>

            <div class="col-category col-xs-3">
                < <a class="form-group level1" href="">title</a>
                <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>   
                <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-category col-xs-3">  
                <a class="form-group level1" href="">title</a>
                <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>   
                <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>
            </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: Did you mean to paste in something?

Comment: It depends on your structure (whether all elements share same parent or one parent per row of elements or one parent per column of elements). All answers without seeing your markup (HTML) could end up being wrong because they would be based on assumptions.

Comment: I have included a sample of my code in my question. It's a three column menu.

Comment: `.row > div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(2){...}` - That seems to be what you need.

Comment: You're the man Harry, worked perfectly. Many thanks.

Comment: And you suspect that it might not be possible because...???

Comment: @jord49 you should have tried it before posting a question.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is. You can use one of the pseudo-classes like [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child):

```css
div.row > div:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(2){
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row ms-category">
  <div class="col-category col-xs-3">
    <a class="form-group level1" href="">title</a>
    <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>
    <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-category col-xs-3">
    <a class="form-group level1" href="">title</a>
    <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>
    <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-category col-xs-3">
    <a class="form-group level1" href="">title</a>
    <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>
    <a class="form-group level2" href="">title</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Pseudo-classes indices begin with one, so the rule above says: select the second anchor that is a child of the second div that is the child of any div with the row class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course! For example, if I have

```
<div id="myId">
  <div>Dummy 1</div>
  <div>Dummy 2</div>
  <div> 
    <div>Sub dummy 1</div>
    <div>Target</div>
    <div>Sub dummy 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can target the `<div>Target</div>` element as follows:

```
#myId > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) {
  /*styles*/
}
```